# Best approach for git-like interface

Tags: c++, git, user-interface, executable, command-line-interface

I'm writing a little command line todo app that has a general git-like interface.

It has several tasks it can perform: `add`, `list`, `complete`, ... all of these should be accessible via the `todo <task>` interface. Eg `todo list`.

Like with git, some of these task take variables or options, and the `todo` app can also take options (which are applicable to any type of task, e.g. the location of the config file).

Eventually one should be able to write something like:

```
todo -c ~/.config/todorc add --desc "walk the dog"
```

Note the order of things here: the global options are given (and can only be given) *before* the actual task. The skeleton for a typical call is then:

```
todo [global options] <task> [task options/arguments]
```

I'm writing this project in C++ and the basic backend library is finished. I'm trying to figure out how to write the user interface now.

Should I use one big `main` that handles every task separatly or should I split up the program into several subprograms and call them from a simple shell script (which is what git does if I'm correct). The latter seems easier to maintain, but makes it harder to pass on the global options to the task executable.

Is there any literature on this subject?

Comment: Why on earth would you want a `git` like interface? Even the command-line crazies are trying to replace it with a better command-line interface, and you know your interface is the worst interface ever created when the Unix guys want to make a new CLI for it.

Comment: @DeadMG While that's absolutely true, I believe OP is asking how to implement the general pattern of "subcommands", which aren't inherently bad. In fact, Mercurial's CLI uses them exclusively, and it's the most intuitive and efficient CLI I have ever used. I want to pay the guys who did it many dollars for the time `hg st`, `hg d fi<TAB>`, `hg ci`, etc. have saved me.

Comment: You could check how taskwarrior solves this (I guess they use a single executable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote it is for a **little**  command line application. Then I would go for one single binary. The easiest way to go is probably to use [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

From my point of view constraining the position of some options is a very bad idea. It will confuse most of the user. The worst case is when position change the semantic of the option. `gcc` did that with the `-l` option and 10 years after you still find new users complaining about their program not linking correctly.