# How to implement git-like or conda-like external cli scripts to be aggregated up by super script?

Tags: command-line-interface

I like how git command line interface works. In particular, the fact that some commans can be handled by external scripts.

Recently I discovered something similar in **anaconda** for python, i.e. conda-* scripts on $PATH

> conda-build        conda-convert      conda-index
>   conda-metapackage  conda-pipbuild     conda-skeleton

get listed in conda help  as

```
external commands:
    build        tool for building conda packages
    convert      various tools to convert conda packages
    index        Update package index metadata files in given directories
    metapackage  <could not extract description>
    pipbuild     tool for building conda packages just using pip install
    skeleton     create skeleton recipes for packages from hosting sites
```

Are there any standard libraries that provide discovery (according to some interface), help aggregation and handling of external commands?

I would be happy to use something similar for my application. Ideally, external scripts maybe written in potentially any language.

## Also see

- Fork of a small script called [**conda-workon**](https://gist.github.com/ewiger/a2253139eaed61e52761) that respects the conda protocol for help discovery and is picked up by **conda help**.
- [Best approach for git-like interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440299/best-approach-for-git-like-interface)